# How to refactor code into a method in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In below code, I want to put below two line from mounted hook into the loadExtraData function. How can I do it? What I am trying to do is to move all the logic into the method in the vue.js.
I want to put this two line of code to the loadExtraData function:
this.model.customerLocation = this.model.customer.locations.filter(x => (x.id === this.model.customerLocationId))[0];
this.customerLocations = this.model.customer.locations;

````js
export default {
    components: {
        InputNumberSpinner,
    },
    props: {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        customerId: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        customerLocationId: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            errorMessage: '',
            validationErrors: {},
            loading: true,
            model: new CustomerRental({ id: this.id }),
            customer: null,
            customerLocations: [],
        };
    },
    
    methods: {
        async loadExtraData(res) {
            //if customer data is already in model, we use it. Else, we fetch it through customer api
            const promises = [];
            if (this.model.customerId === res.customerId && this.model.customer) {
                res.customer = this.model.customer;
            } else if (res.customerId !== null) {
                promises.push(api.customers.getById(res.customerId).then(x => res.customer = x));
            }

            if (promises.length > 0) {
                await Promise.all(promises);
            }
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        await api.cache.checkIfOutOfDate(['customerRentals']);

        if (this.model.id === 0) {
            promises.push(api.customers.getById(this.customerId).then(
                x => this.customer = x
            ));
        }
        //fetch customerRentals
        if(this.model.id > 0) {
            api.customerRentals.getById(this.model.id)
            .then(async response => {
                await this.loadExtraData(response);
                this.model = response;
                this.model.customerLocation = this.model.customer.locations.filter(x => (x.id === this.model.customerLocationId))[0];
                this.customerLocations = this.model.customer.locations;
            }).catch(error => {
                this.loading = false;
                handleHttpError(error);
            });
        }
    }
};```
````

Comment: So what is the problem to put it at the end of `loadExtraData` function ?